# Debian debian filesystem layout

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

Is there somewhere where i can find out what is the Debian file system layout?
I would like to create a folder and inside of that folder i want to install Apache, PHP, MySQL, PostgreSQL but i want to install them in the same way as if they were installed in a Debian distro using apt for example.

i.e.: binaries in /usr/bin, conf in /etc (in my case ./MyFolder/etc/) etc..

So whant i am looking is where can i find out what exactly is the place that the files of Apache, PHP, MySQL are placed in debian?

Comment: "i want to install them in the same way as if they were installed in a Debian distro": There is probably a reason why you want to do that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to make a WAMP like app and let's say that my app will be installed in C:\MyAMP Inside that folder i want to make a linux like file system structure where i will put apache, mysql, php. Ex: C:\MyAMP\etc\apache2\httpd.conf, etc...

Comment: What? WAMP, LAMP, XAMP, ... already exist. So why re-invent the wheel? And then in such a lousy way?

Comment: So it's on Windows. I don't think it is very meaningful to try to enforce a "LSB-like" file structure on Windows systems. Some programs use some kind of "Unix-like layout" on Windows but most don't, so it might not be really possible. Anyway install a virtual Debian server systems (it is quite lightweight) and do some "dpkg -L apache2.2-bin" to have an idea on the layout.

Comment: @mailq: And why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian is a LSB compliant distribution. So the standards are described (not exclusively) at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base

*But you won't install software at places where the package manager will also install the software!* So I'll advice you not to do what you want.

Comment: +1 The LSB defines places where it's acceptable to install user software.  If you want to install stuff in the same place as the package manager, then create a package and let the package manager manage it.  Otherwise, you're going to wind up playing tug-of-war.

Comment: Also see the [Debian Policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html).  Debian does make some exceptions and defines some additional restrictions for official packages.